# Копирование файлов в Windows

Tags: windows, файлы, отправка, архивация

Доброго времени суток!

Дружу с Windows. И заметил такой момент, что копирование 
группы маленьких файлов маленьких занимает очень много времени,
не смотря на небольшой объём. То есть один файл на 700 MB 
скопируется за время 12 сек с одного харда на другой, а много 
маленьких за 1 минуту, за 5 минут... 
Само собой время значительно зависит от фрагментированности диска,
от размера файликов мелких, от их разбросанности на HDD...

Поэтому приведу другой пример. Отправляю аналогично с компа на комп 
по Wi-fi по каналу имеющему реальную скорость 1,5 мбайт/сек 
Получаю те же результаты... Что при куче файликов скорость снижается.
По сути та же запись с HDD на HDD только через узкий канал.
Но при передаче маленьких файликов получаем меньшую скорость 
(440 кбайт/сек). Вот.

Собственно вопрос =)
Наверное же логично передавать не каждый файл по отдельности по сети,
а как бы несколько сразу... Чтобы сто пятьсот раз не обращаться за файлом...
То есть одна машина бы их в оперативку кидала, там объединяла и на другую бы 
пересылала по каналу связи. А не по отдельности.
Вот... Если это вдруг работает не так, а каждый файлик по отдельности запрашивается кэшируется и отправляется, то может где-то в лесу реестра завалялась такая настроечка...
Подскажите, если не так мыслю... Или так =)

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Windows медленно работает с каталогами, поэтому самое логичное уйти с нее.

Comment: Только из-за проблем с каталогами? Давайте перечислим все минусы Linux`а...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто используйте `ZIP`-архивы.